# CSP not detecting smart card minidriver on remote desktop

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, remote-desktop, smartcard

I'm writing a simple program which uses smart card to for xml signing.

Sample code:

```
var cspParams = new CspParameters(1, "Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider")
{
    KeyPassword = password,
    Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseDefaultKeyContainer
 };

var rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);
```

This code works fine on local machine, but on remote desktop I got following message:

> "A smart card was detected but is not the one required for the current operation. The smart card you are using may be missing required driver software or a required certificate."

Comment: Not a programming issue, I don't think. [This](http://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/8113-smartcard-login.html) might help.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by remote desktop security policy, which redirects all requests for smart card from remote machine to a local one. Use a different [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) client and server.